# Copying the current div content to a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in the process of creating a tool for my workplace. It's just for myself but mostly to learn html, CSS and JS.

I have a timer here to monitor how long I spend on tasks.
I would like for the timer to reset and at the same time log the current time to a text area.
I have this working, however when the timer is stopped and I reset, the current paused time does not log to the text area but the timer resets.

I would be grateful for any help, here is the code I have currently:

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 0;
var stoptime = 0;
var splitcounter = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;

function startstop() {
  var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
  }
}

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.innerHTML = formattime(timediff, '');
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 10);
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 60) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds;
}

function resetclock() {
  flagstop = 0;
  stoptime = 0;
  splitdate = '';
  window.clearTimeout(refresh);

  if (flagclock == 1) {
    var resetdate = new Date();
    var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
    counter(resettime);
  } else {
    clock.innerHTML = "00:00:0";
  }
}

//Split function

function splittime() {
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    if (splitdate != '') {
      var splitold = splitdate.split(':');
      var splitnow = clock.innerHTML.split(':');
      var numbers = new Array();
      var i = 0
      for (i; i < splitold.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new Array();
        numbers[i][0] = splitold[i] * 1;
        numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i] * 1;
      }
      if (numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0]) {
        numbers[1][1] += 60;
        numbers[0][1] -= 1;
      }
      if (numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0]) {
        numbers[2][1] += 10;
        numbers[1][1] -= 1;
      }
    }
    splitdate = clock.innerHTML;
    output.innerHTML += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.innerHTML + '\n';
    console.log("split");
  }
}

function time() {
  splittime();
  resetclock();
}
```

```html
<input id="startstopbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btn" id='btn' value="Start" onclick="startstop();">
<input id="resetbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btnRst1" id='btnRst1' value="Reset" onclick="time();" />
<div id="clock" class="timerClock" value="00:00:00">00:00:00</div>
<br>
<textarea id="output" spellcheck="false" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new function:

```
function logTime() {
    const time = document.getElementById('clock').getAttribute('value');
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '\n' + time; 
}
```

Add it into the `else` scope:

```
else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
    logTime(); // New addition
  }
```

update the element value, and not just the innerHTML:

```
if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.innerHTML = formattime(timediff, '');
    clock.setAttribute('value', formattime(timediff, '')); // New addition
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 10);
  }
```

---

Test:

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 0;
var stoptime = 0;
var splitcounter = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;

function startstop() {
  var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
    logTime();
  }
}

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.innerHTML = formattime(timediff, '');
    clock.setAttribute('value', formattime(timediff, ''));
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 10);
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 60) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds;
}

function resetclock() {
  flagstop = 0;
  stoptime = 0;
  splitdate = '';
  window.clearTimeout(refresh);

  if (flagclock == 1) {
    var resetdate = new Date();
    var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
    counter(resettime);
  } else {
    clock.innerHTML = "00:00:0";
  }
}

//Split function

function splittime() {
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    if (splitdate != '') {
      var splitold = splitdate.split(':');
      var splitnow = clock.innerHTML.split(':');
      var numbers = new Array();
      var i = 0
      for (i; i < splitold.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new Array();
        numbers[i][0] = splitold[i] * 1;
        numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i] * 1;
      }
      if (numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0]) {
        numbers[1][1] += 60;
        numbers[0][1] -= 1;
      }
      if (numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0]) {
        numbers[2][1] += 10;
        numbers[1][1] -= 1;
      }
    }
    splitdate = clock.innerHTML;
    output.innerHTML += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.innerHTML + '\n';
    console.log("split");
  }
}

function time() {
  splittime();
  resetclock();
}

function logTime() {
    const time = document.getElementById('clock').getAttribute('value');
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '\n' + time; 
}
```

```html
<input id="startstopbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btn" id='btn' value="Start" onclick="startstop();">
<input id="resetbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btnRst1" id='btnRst1' value="Reset" onclick="time();" />
<div id="clock" class="timerClock" value="00:00:00">00:00:00</div>
<br>
<textarea id="output" spellcheck="false" rows="4" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, this is great - Thank you for your help - Ive removed the split counter as I noticed it would log the time when pressing stop aswell as reset and only the reset logs would count toward the split counter. - I tried to include both but could not figure it out just yet, if you know how that could be done that would be a huge help.